How can I extract text from a web page using flutter
I want the same functionality that https://cooked.wiki/ has but I don't know how to replicate. It takes the stories out of recipe pages and gives you the ingredients and directions. I'm using google_mlkit_text_recognition: ^0.11.0 to scan recipe books but need to do so like cooked.wiki for webpages. User friendly experience is everything.. any ideas?
Made some progress.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

class WebScrapingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebScrapingPageState createState() => _WebScrapingPageState();
}

class _WebScrapingPageState extends State<WebScrapingPage> {
  String _title = "No title found";
  List<String> _ingredients = [];
  List<String> _directions = [];
  final TextEditingController _urlController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> fetchRecipeDetails(String url) async {
    print("Fetching recipe details for URL: $url");
    if (!url.startsWith('http://') && !url.startsWith('https://')) {
      url = 'https://cooked.wiki/https://' + url;
    }

    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        extractRecipeDetails(response.body);
      } else {
        print("Failed to load the page with status code: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to load recipe: $e');
    }
  }


void extractRecipeDetails(String htmlContent) {
  dom.Document document = parser.parse(htmlContent);

  setState(() {
    _title = document.querySelector('h1')?.text.trim() ?? "No title found";
    print('Extracted title: $_title');

   
    _ingredients = document.querySelectorAll('.mntl-structured-ingredients__list-item')
        .map((element) {
          var quantity = element.querySelector('[data-ingredient-quantity]')?.text.trim() ?? '';
          var unit = element.querySelector('[data-ingredient-unit]')?.text.trim() ?? '';
          var name = element.querySelector('[data-ingredient-name]')?.text.trim() ?? '';
          return "$quantity $unit $name";
        })
        .where((text) => text.isNotEmpty)
        .toList();
    print('Ingredients: $_ingredients');

    _directions = document.querySelectorAll('#recipe__steps-content_1-0 .mntl-sc-block-html')
        .map((element) => element.text.trim())
        .where((text) => text.isNotEmpty)
        .toList();
    print('Directions: $_directions');
  });
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Recipe Details'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _urlController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Recipe URL',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: () => fetchRecipeDetails(_urlController.text),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(_title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text("Ingredients", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
              ..._ingredients.map((ingredient) => ListTile(title: Text(ingredient))).toList(),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text("Directions", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
              ..._directions.map((direction) => ListTile(title: Text(direction))).toList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This works for allrecipes.com
How do I generalize it to work with various websites? Is that possible?
The answer is here somewhere.. https://github.com/mattsegura/Savor

This is called web scraping. Essentially you can make an http request to a website, then you parse the html, then you can extract some information from the html document.


use this :

SelectableText("your text")


dont use on web :

Text("your text")

or if you didn't access to code and want to extract text's use this

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/extract-text-from-image/adkbpbalabenjlfngiefoifoebjpbjjl?hl=en-US&utm_source=ext_sidebar

